# I am trying to make pop ups for a game I am working on. The button shows up and but the pop up will not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax, popup

`I am making a game for a class. I wanted to make an old fashion web choose your own adventure type game that I remember playing years ago. So as if you go the wrong way, you may die. So I am working on one of those dead ends and I want a pop up to happen as they failed. The button works and I know the pop up is designed. I just for the life of me can not figure why it is not working. I have watched several videos and hoped that it was a simple error but nothing has helped yet.

```js
const openyoudiedbuttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-youdied-target]")
//const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay")

openyoudiedbuttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const youdied = 
document.querySelector(button.dataset.youdiedTarget)
    openyoudied(youdied)
  })
})

//overlay.addEventListener("click", () => {
//  const youdied = document.querySelectorAll(".youdied.active")
//})

function openyoudied(youdied) {
  if (youdied == null) return
  youdied.classlist.add("active")
  overlay.classlist.add("active")
}
```

```css
.dead {color: #ca0d0d;
font-size: xx-large;
}

.youdied{
width: 300px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
background:black;
color: var(--red);
position: fixed;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0);
transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
border: 1px solid rgb(134, 29, 29); 
border-radius: 10px;
z-index: 10;
width: 400px
}
.youdied.active {transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.youdied-header{
padding: 10px, 15px;
font-weight: bold;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
border-bottom: 1px solid var(--red);
}
.youdied-header .title{
font-size: 1.25rem;
font-weight: bold;
}

#overlay{
position: fixed;
opacity: 0;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
transition: 200ms ease-in-out;
background-color: black 0, 0 ,0 .7;
pointer-events: none;
}

#overlay.active{
pointer-events: all;
opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dead">
<h1>The Pond</h1>
<img src="pond.webp"
height="300" width="600" ></div>      
<div class="youdied" id="youdied">
    <div class="youdied">You Died<br>
         As you reached for the coat. <br>
A pale hand grabs you and<br>
 pulls you under the water.
    <img src="ghosthand.jpg"
    height="150" width="250" >
<div class="box-center">
    <a href="final.html">Try Again?</a> &nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<button data-youdied-target="#youdied">Grab Your Brother's 
coat</button>
</div>
```

I can not really say what I have tried. I have tried moving things around and making changes to my code. WHen I say I am new. I am not joking

Comment: Did you check the console for errors?  It's not possible to debug code in images, so we can't do that unless you update your question to provide a runnable sample (use the `<>` button to make a snippet)

Comment: I will try that, i do apologize as it is my first time asking a question

Comment: Yogi, Why might I use the dialog element?

Comment: I corrected a couple of typos: addEventlistener needs a capital `L`, there's no overlay included in this sample so I took out the code that uses it.

Comment: There's another typo - classlist needs to be `classList` again capital L - does that make it work?

Comment: James, I fixed those and found other issues like that. I knew it was case sensitive, I just didn’t know to that degree. I tried both with and with out the overlay but no luck

Comment: Please rephrase your question with your function and variable names so we can get I clear idea of what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using an alert at first. See where you messd up!

Once that works, you can add the fancy bells-and-whistles to make your code work.

I'd also suggest looking up the proper way of formatting for best readability!